# After completely installation and done all the work i am getting Permission denied error do any one have solution

Tags: python, image, tesseract, python-tesseract, text-recognition

code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/Users/navroop/Desktop/text reco/tesseract'
img = cv2.imread("car.png")
```

---

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 58
     55 file = open("recognized.txt", "a")
     57 # Apply OCR on the cropped image
---> 58 text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped)
     60 # Appending the text into file
     61 file.write(text)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/navroop/Desktop/text reco/tesseract'
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

I have tried to clone the repo of tesseract and then mentioning he path of that downloaded file
and using it for extracting image from a png file

Comment: Going forward, probably notice that you get a preview of what your post will look like below the editing pane. If your screen is wide enough, you also get a help button at the right of the editor’s menu strip, with a link to the full [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: What is the ownership and permissions of the problematic directory? How exactly was it populated (`git clone`, `pip install`, or what? Using `sudo`? Then that's your error right there).